# How to build an unorthodox project structure with dotnet cli

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

I have been trying to build the following project structure with dotnet cli on netcoreapp3.1:

project_root:
             project.sln

```
         projecct1
         --------project1.csproj
         project2
         --------project2.csproj
         third_party
         --------third_party1
                 ------------third_party1.csproj
```

The third party project is referenced in one of the projects and it is in its self a netsandard2.0 assembly
running dotnet build produces the following error:

```
 error NETSDK1005: Assets file '...\third-party\third_party1\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

Building the third party on its own works fine.
I realize that the error stems from the structure of the project. Any ideas how I can build the project with getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so answering my own question. The problem was not the structure. When I built the project in command line I use `dotnet build -c Release -f netcoreapp3.1`

Since the project is a mix of netcoreapp3.1 and standard2.0 assemblies the standard2.0 assemblies failed to compile. If your framework is set in the csproj file not need for -f apparently.